# How to get amplitudes only for chosen qubits?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

For computation, I use `N` working qubits and `M` ancilla qubits.

```
qubits = QuantumRegister(N, name='q')
ancilla = QuantumRegister(M, name='anc')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qubits, ancilla)
```

Then at the end of a program to get state vector I do:

```
result = execute(circuit, Aer.backend, shots=shots).result()
return result.get_statevector(circuit)
```

Because of ancilla qubits are usually used for computation/uncomputation steps it means that the end states of them are $|0..0 \rangle$ (at least in some cases) and I am not interested in them due to unnessasary information about `M` ancilla qubits contained in `get_statevector(circuit)`.

Is it possible to get state vector so it will show amplitudes only for `N` working qubit?

I have an idea to solve this equation to find $S_N$ (state vector of `N` working qubits): 
$$ S_N \otimes I_M = S_{M+N}$$
but probably `qiskit` can do it internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `statevector_simulator` will always return the statevector for all the qubits in the circuit. You can however add snapshots over a subset of qubits, so you could add this right at the end of your circuit and use the information you get from that instead.

```
from qiskit.extensions.simulator import snapshot
qc.snapshot("one_qubit", qubits=[0])
qc.snapshot("many_qubits", qubits=[0,2])

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = execute(qc, backend).result()

snapshots = result.data()['snapshots']['statevector'].items()
```

Comment: is `qc` a `QuantumCircuit` instance?

Comment: I can't understand the output of `result.data()['snapshots']['statevector'][snapshot_name]`. Is it possible to get a state vector array with $2^N$ elements where $N$ is the number of working qubits. After the code snippet from your answer I get the following:

Comment: `[[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]]`

Comment: It has entries for amplitudes for all the qubits, but the qubits which are not asked for are considered to be in the 0 state. This means you can do what you suggested below, and only take the number of amplitudes you need. 

For example 
```qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
qc.snapshot("one_qubit", qubits=[0])
qc.snapshot("many_qubits", qubits=[0,1])
```
returns 
```many_qubits  :  [[[0.5000000000000001, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.4999999999999999, 0.0]]]
one_qubit  :  [[[0.7071067811865476, 0.0], [0.7071067811865475, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]]
```

Comment: (It may be easier to copy and paste that code and what it generates somewhere you can read it better!)

Comment: >but the qubits which are not asked for are considered to be in the 0 state.
Does it mean that it's a partial solution like I answered below?

Comment: Yes it is similar to your solution, but in the snapshot they are guaranteed to be 0, so you can instantly dismiss them whereas you say in your solution you need to assume that they are.

Answer (score 1):

If I can be sure that all ancilla qubits are in $ | 0...0 \rangle$ then that their state vector is:
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \\
... \\
0  
\end{bmatrix}

with $2^M\times 1$ dimension.

So I can take the first $2^N $ elements out of `result.get_statevector(circuit)` to find the state vector of working qubits.

But it's just a partial solution.